# Passing drawbox polygon to geoprocessor

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder, feature-set

I am building an app in the ArcGIS Web AppBuilder.

I am trying to pass the geometry resulting from the drawbox dijit to a geoprocessor. Its an extent.

But when I attempt it and log the parameter to console from the geoprocessing script its always empty.

I get the geometry from the drawbox dijit like so :-

```
_onDrawComplete: function(graphic) {
  var geometry = graphic.geometry;
  this._bathyList(this.bathyList, geometry)
},
```

I then want to pass this geometry into a geoprocessor. I tried passing it in directly and it complained it needed to be a gpfeatureset.

So I have attempted to create a gpfeatureset which seems to have got round the above error.

The problem is that when I log the param out on the geoprocessing end it is always null.

```
var features = [];
  features.push(geometry);

  var featureSet = new FeatureSet();
  featureSet.features = features;

  console.log(geometry)
  console.log(featureSet)

  // setup gp stuff and params
  var params = { "boolList":boollist, "poly": featureSet };
  var gp = new
  Geoprocessor('https://arcgispreprodent.admiralty.co.uk/server/rest/services/Jim/BathyClip/GPServer/BathyClip')

  gp.submitJob(params, this._processresults, this._jobstatus, this._joberr)
},
```

I am not sure how to debug this now, I assume I must be building an invalid gpfeatureset but it doesnt error.

I can change the datatypes, I can chacge the gp script, I just dont know how to get it to pass the polygon.

Heres my gp script

```
boolList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
poly = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.AddMessage('Param 0 : ' + boolList)
arcpy.AddMessage('Param 1 : ' + poly)

Output_Zip_File = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, 'output.zip')

tiflist = [u"Whole_UK_Mosaic", u"Whole_UK_COMORG"]


def cliptif(clippee, clipper, output):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(clipper)
    extent = desc.extent
    arcpy.Clip_management(clippee, str(extent), output, in_template_dataset=poly, clipping_geometry="ClippingGeometry")

for i in range(len(tiflist)):
    if boolList[i]:
        outTif = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, 'output'+str(i) + '.tif')
        cliptif(tiflist[i], poly, outTif)

zipper = zipfile.ZipFile(Output_Zip_File, 'w')
for i in range(len(tiflist)):
    zipper.write(os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, 'output'+str(i) + '.tif'), tiflist[i]+'.tif')
zipper.close()


for i in range(len(tiflist)):
    if boolList[i]:
        outTif = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchFolder, 'output'+str(i) + '.tif')
        arcpy.Delete_management(outTif)

arcpy.SetParameter(2, Output_Zip_File)
```

I am not sure why my second parameter is always null when logging from the geoprocessor, I might be falling foul of asynchronous stuff somewhere or building feature set wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was I was just trying to pass the geometry returned from the drawbox, I should pass the whole graphic into the featureset not just the geometry.